# Установка фокуса в div contenteditable="true"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Здравствуйте,подскажите,как быть,есть div

```
<div id="editable_zone" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

я в него перемещаю изображения

```
 $('body').on('click', 'img', function () {$(this).toggleClass('selimg');});

 $(".selimg").appendTo("#editable_zone").resizable().parent().draggable({ containment: 'parent' }).click(function () {
          alert("окей");
        });
```

Но проблема в том,что после передвижения изображения ,вводить в div текст можно только над картинкой,можно ли самому устанавливать focus  и писать где нужно?
Подскажите,почему не работает **resizable()**-код то вроде рабочий.
Заранее спасибо!
P.S. вот https://jsfiddle.net/Zkolya_linkoln/zph9wwhg/2/ правда тут  resizable() работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) По поводу ресайза - у меня картинка вполне даже расайзится)

2) По поводу текста. В момент когда вы делаете картинку resizable она оборачивается в враппер (div), который хранит элемент картинки и "уголок" для ресайза. Когда мы начинаем что-то писать - это попадает именно во враппер.

3) И наконец главное - если в контейнер добавить абсолютно позиционированный элемент - писать в него уже не удастся.

```
<div contenteditable="true" style="border: 1px solid black; height: 300px;">
    <div contenteditable="false" style="position: absolute; border: 1px solid black; width: 50px; height: 50px; top: 50px; left: 50px;">1<div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gccehnf6/

FF Баг: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=462758 (к сожалению пока не хочет открываться, не могу проверить, возможно это один из потомков этого бага)

Решение - не добавлять картинку в редактор а обрабатывать ее отдельно, можно положить редактируемую область и картинку в еще один DIV (position: relative), а скроллинг допускать во внешнем диве.

**UPD: Добавил пример**

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.editor {     
    height: 300px;
}

.img {
    position: absolute; 
    border: 1px solid black; 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px; 
    top: 50px; 
    left: 50px;
}

//...

<div class="wrapper" contenteditable="false">
    <div contenteditable="true" class="editor"> </div>
    <div class="img">1</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bxnmmh88/

Comment: Большое спасибо,за подробное разъяснение,очень помогли!